# Resume Logshipping after Primary database restored

Tags: sql-server-2008, disaster-recovery, log-shipping

We have Database (D1) as a primary database and Log shipping setup to the secondary database called (LS_D1). Now what we are doing is taking backup of D1 database and restore it on D2 database. We do schema and data changes for new Release deployment on to D2 database.

What we want is to restore D2 database on D1 database and resume the log shipping to the LS_D1 database without copying backup file. Copying a backup file from primary data center to DR data center cost us too much money for every Release so that's why we want to resume the Log shipping.

When i tried to do this LSN numbers got out of sync, is there any way that we can solve this problem ? or can we have any other alternative to Log Shipping that can provide us DR capability and solve this problem ?

Note: Any solution that can require one time cost of log shipping would also be fine.

Thanks,
Piyush Patel

Answer (score 5):

When you restored the primary the log shipping has broken. The only way to resume it is to re-initiate it, with a new full backup. End of discussion.

> We do schema and data changes for new Release deployment on to D2 database.

And that is your real problem. Do all changes as *code* changes and deploy by running deployment scripts. When you want to migrate the changes done in development on D2 to D1 simply run the migration scripts *on D1*. Use [Visual Studio Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for instance.

Even w/o proper development process you could had applied the changes between D2 and D1 as scripts run on D1, and don't break the log shipping relation. Eg. tools like [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) would had done the job.

Comment: The problem we are facing is we want to deploy the Release within 8 hours, and we do have some data patches to be execute while deployment which takes more than 8 hours. so to overcome this problem we are creating D2 database a week before and do our Release deployment on it mean while production is running on D1 database. 

Night before go Live, we restore D2 to D1 or we can point our production directly to the D2 itself.

Comment: Make the data patches on D1, eg. use partitions and staging tables. You can't achieve what you want w/o breaking log shipping.

Comment: Can you elaborate more how can i use partitions and staging tables ? we wants to deploy new release within 8 hours window and only the data patches stopping us to do that.

Comment: Please open a separate questions.

Comment: What @PiyushPatel is talking can be achieved. Please see below solution that I posted. It is being PROD tested on our environment where we have to failover and failback 50-60 databases at one shot. Obviously, we have partially automated the solution, but proper testing will be required to understand the bits and pieces.

Comment: @Kin: you are doing something else: freeze the primary, recover the secondary, make changes on the secondary, then apply the changes to the primary and resume. OP is asking about *reverting the primary back in time to an point prior to current secondary*. Nothing can recover from *that*.

Comment: @RemusRusanu if you see what OP wants -- "What we want is to restore D2 database on D1 database and resume the log shipping to the LS_D1 database without copying backup file. Copying a backup file from primary data center to DR data center cost us too much money for every Release so that's why we want to resume the Log shipping." then it is the same what I have answered .. He wants to do the changes on D2 (sec) server and then resume with the changes done on D2 the log shipping from D1 to D2.

Comment: @Kin: there is also an LS_D1. And I think OP *already* let LS_D1 and D1 diverge. Yes, in future a variation of freezing D1 in place and messing with the inner of LS could work, but I would much rather see him adopt a scripting based deployment for schema changes, and a proper ETL pipeline that does not require +8 hours of downtime *and* work on a secondary server...

Comment: @RemusRusanu we have large database and from the past experience we have come to know that data patches takes more than 24 hours to execute (we have tried direct sql, ETL pipeline). so we have to start preparing our database a week ago for new Release deployment. we are also running the replication between D1 and D2 to insert one week of production data to D2 with some transform logic as D1 and D2 contains different schema.

Comment: So by proposing this solution we have achieved minimum outage on database but it has some disadvantage like we have to re-initialize the Log shipping which cost us more on every Release deployment, so i was trying to think is there any way that we can resume the Log shipping anyhow..

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the situation that you are facing currently and got creative with logshipping as there is no pause button for Log shipping.

We have implemented similar solution as a part of our Disaster Recovery fail-over testing -

Note: Below will not be clear as this site does not have any functionality for inserting a table from excel. But if you put below sequence in excel with header primary server and secondary server, it will be more comprehensible....

MAKE SURE THAT YOU TEST THIS BEFORE PUTTING IT IN PROD -- AS THE POST IS AS IS WITHOUT ANY RESPONSIBILITY OF DATA LOSS !!

**ON Primary Server:**

1) disable Log shipping (LS) job - Backup

2) Run LS Backup jobs manually

4) Kill all connections to database

5) Backup log(s) with norecovery (using T-SQL)  - backup log db_name to disk = '\share\LogShip\db_name\db_name_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.trn' with norecovery
with norecovery

12) Restore log(s) with recovery (Using T-SQL, Log backups that were created on step 10) - restore log db_name from disk = '\share\LogShip\db_name\db_name_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.trn'
with recovery

13) Run LS Backups jobs on Primary Server

15) Enable SQL Logins and sync them

16) Enable LS jobs

**ON secondary Server:**

3) Run LS Copy and Restore jobs manually to make sure all the t-logs have been applied to Secondary database.

6) Run LS Copy jobs

7)Restore database(s) with recovery (Using T-SQL, Log backups that were created on step 5) - restore log db_name from disk = '\share\LogShip\db_name\db_name_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.trn'
with recovery

8) Sync logins

**AT THIS POINT DATABASES HAVE BEEN RECOVERED AND CAN BE ACCESSED**

Now fail back --- after step 8

9) Kill all connections

10) Backup log with norecovery (using T-SQL)  - backup log db_name to disk = '\share\LogShip\db_name\db_name_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.trn'
with norecovery

11) Manually copy TRN file(s) to Primary Server (Created in step 10)

14) Run LS Copy and Restore jobs on secondary (check log shipping report)

15) Enable SQL Logins

16) Enable LS jobs

Comment: ,what i have understood is you are changing the secondary database and then somehow you are resuming the log shipping between Primary and secondary database. our scenario is we have log shipping running between D1 and LS_D1 database, a week before go Live we restore D1 to D2 and run new deployment on D2. night before go live we will restore D2 on D1 and wants to resume Log shipping to LS_D1. What we are trying to achieve is minimum outage on database while deploying new release (schema changes, and BIG Data Patches)

Comment: @PiyushPatel: you have to understand that *even if* you are able to get the solution to work, the 'BIG Data Patches' will translate into 'BIG Logs' which will have to be shipped to LS_D1 at the cost you want to avoid.