# Can Log Shipping be recovered and resumed by scripts after DR?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

Server A has DB1 log shipping to Server B as DB1_LS in a DR environment. Before the company DR exercise, I scripted out the log shipping configuration from DB1 properties window so I basically got one scripts with two parts, one part to turn on Server A (primary), one part to run on Server B (Secondary).

During the DR exercise, I unchecked the log shipping box in the log shipping property on Server A. So basically it broke the log shipping and removed the copy and restore jobs on server B and backup job on server A, but not removing the DB1_LS DB, that is expected.  I brought DB1_LS online through recovery, thus it simulated that Server A was destroyed and we still got DB running on Server B.   All usual stuff.

**Problem:**

After DR exercise, I need to do RTR(Return to Ready), IE reestablish the log shipping process.  Instead of going to Server A to do it through GUI windows, I ran the script part meant for Server A and log shipping definition on server A was back, good.  Then I ran the script part meant for server B, it complained something and threw an error (sorry, I didn't record the exact error screen), basically saying it couldn't use the existing DB1_LS which was online already; I then decided to drop DB1_LS, re-ran the script part meant for Server B, then it complained DB was missing.  In a word, my whole idea was to use script (instead of manual) to re-establish Log shipping after DR, it didn't seem to work at all (at least for the script part meant for Server B).  Then I am wondering what is the purpose for us to script out the log shipping?  Was I doing something wrong?  Is re-establishing Log shipping through script even possible?  I am very puzzled at this.  We got 30+ log shipping DBs so I really want to find a script way to do RTR or re-establish them after log shipping is broken.

Comment: Basically you brought the databases online, may or may not have unsynchronized them through DML, then tried to make things as they were. What you'll need to do is either reverse log ship or restore the databases on Server B as they were before the exercise in order to use the script to setup log shipping again. All the script does is setup the object, the database is still needed to be prepared and ready.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Server A is prod server so I can't do reverse log shipping to write to the Prod server.  It was a DR exercise, not a real disaster.  In a real disaster, I would do reverse log shipping.  But in my case, I just need to re-establish log shipping in a simple way than many button clicking, path copying and pasting etc.   When it involves 30+ DBs, I really want to find a lazy way.   Anybody else had the same situation?

Comment: The lazy way would be to have a script (many are online) that can restore the databases on Server B from the backups on Server A, leave them in restoring mode, and then setup  log shipping again with the scripts you already have.

Comment: Sean, do you mean I have to restore from server A in order to achieve what I want?   If that is the case, then I would go back to manual wizard way. so no way to reuse the DB1_LS for my purpose?

Comment: Sean, my Server A and Server B are far far away and server B is in a DR domain.  My DBs on server A are pretty big, some are 800GB even over 1TB. Backup and then transfer backup file then restore backup on a remote connection will take tremendous time and bandwidth.  So basically there is no way to reuse the DB1_LS database on my server B?  I have to get a brand new full backup from server A???  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I even tried this.  script out DB1_LS database on server B,  delete DB1_LS database and use the script to create a new DB with same name but empty.  When I tried to use the script part meant for Server B, it still didn't work.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Log Shipping process is somewhat of a mystery here so let me explain that and then answer the questions you have.

Log shipping works by taking transaction log backups of a primary database and applying them to secondary database(s) through the use of jobs and a shared file location.

In order to apply log backups, the databases that will have the log applied to them must be ready to accept the log restore (in NORECOVERY or STANDBY and must be FULL or BULK_LOGGED recovery model) and must be able to have the log restored to that database (LSNs must match or be within the ranges).

Thus, when the databases were brought online in read/write mode and the DR test was run - the databases are no longer synchronized through LSNs as new operations, etc, were completed on the databases. This means you can no longer restore transaction log backups (simply put).

> Sean, do you mean I have to restore from server A in order to achieve
>   what I want? If that is the case, then I would go back to manual
>   wizard way. so no way to reuse the DB1_LS for my purpose?

Because the databases aren't synchronized at this point by LSN, you'll somehow need to initialize the databases you want as secondary databases to be able to accept the log backups from the primary (prod) database. However you choose to do that is up to you, but the databases will need to be restored and be in NORECOVERY with LSNs that fall within the primary log backup range.

> Sean, my Server A and Server B are far far away and server B is in a
>   DR domain. My DBs on server A are pretty big, some are 800GB even over
>   1TB. Backup and then transfer backup file then restore backup on a
>   remote connection will take tremendous time and bandwidth. So
>   basically there is no way to reuse the DB1_LS database on my server B?
>   I have to get a brand new full backup from server A??? Thanks.

Because of the way decisions made and the way it happened, it doesn't sound like there will be any way to reuse the databases unless you have local backups there that can get you to a sync point in terms of LSNs with the primary database. My guess is you don't.

Let this be a lesson in making sure the technology and process is understood before deciding a path or course of action.

> BTW, I even tried this. script out DB1_LS database on server B, delete
>   DB1_LS database and use the script to create a new DB with same name
>   but empty. When I tried to use the script part meant for Server B, it
>   still didn't work. Just FYI.

That's definitely not going to work as the LSNs will definitely not sync up, nor would any of the information being applied to it in a transaction log (if SOMEHOW you could force it to restore [which you wouldn't be able to]) even be in the database to apply it to.

It seems as though you're missing the fundamentals of how transaction log restores work, so I've included some links.

[Understanding How Restore and Recovery of Backups Work In SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Restore and Recovery Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191253(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Working With Transaction Log Backups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190440(v=sql.105).aspx)

**[Applying Transaction Log Backups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189596(v=sql.105).aspx)**

Comment: Not directly related to this, but do you think the reverse LS steps (9-16)will work @https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/resume-logshipping-after-primary-database-restored, thanks.

Comment: Potentially but you ALREADY stated per response to my comment of reverse log shipping that you didn't want the data from the DR test to end up in production. So while it MAY work, you'll be doing even more damage.